# How can I list the logged in users with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get a list of the logged on users from PowerShell. Is there a command that returns a list of the logged in users, regardless of whether their session is connected or disconnected? I'm only looking for local sessions, but remote sessions would be nice too.

Comment: There is an answer to a simliar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219718/powershell-script-to-see-currently-logged-in-users-domain-and-machine-status

Comment: Also here is great topic about Powershell features. https://powershell.org/2015/08/28/list-users-logged-on-to-your-machines/

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve local sessions: `qwinsta`

To retrieve remote sessions: `qwinsta /server:servername`

Answer (score 1):

Try following one line to find a list of logged on users.

> query user /server:$SERVER

Answer (score 0):

`quser`

This gives connected, disconnected, remote and local logins. Simple and easy.

This also helps when you want to logoff sessions using the `logoff #` where # is the **ID** of the `quser` result